# try to convert textbox value to int within convert method

Tags: wpf

i trying binding textbox value to button IsEnable property but i get an exception.
this is my convert class:

```
    public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string num = value as string;
        int n = int.Parse(num);
        if (n > 10) return true;  
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

this is my xaml code:

```
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mytext,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource convertIntToBool}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,181,-156,-179" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="mytext" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="263,163,-382,-163" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

i get FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: How could anyone convert "TextBox" String into an int?

Comment: but the value parameter is not text? so i can pass it to string variable?

Comment: The value is a String but it contains the String "TextBox", which can't be parsed into an int. The int.Parse method is made to parse Strings containing number into an int like: "5" or "5.5"

Comment: so how can i get number that the user write within the textbox into my convert method?

Comment: i fixed it :) thanks! i used the TryParse method to check if it is a number :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to handle user input in TextBox and make a button enabled or disabled according to this input.

First, you're using int.Parse, meaning that you trust the user to write a number in your TextBox: Don't ever trust user input.

You'll need to use int.TryParse so it doesn't throw an exception if the input isn't a number.

Second, I don't know why you set the TextBox's Text property to "TextBox", that's what is throwing the exception.

Your converter code should look like this:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string num = value as string;
        int n;
        if(int.TryParse(num, out n)) { //return true is the parse worked
            if(n > 10) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```